# GPT2 model training gives, Loss nan during training

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am following [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/fine-tuning-gpt2-for-question-answering/31895) tutorial of huggingface library. Since I have a large dataset so I have used Dataloader and created batches. But am facing this error. Here is the process of creating batches,

```
 class FeedbackEssentials(Dataset):
def __init__(self, qa_pairs, tokenizer, max_length):
    self.qa_pairs = qa_pairs
    self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    self.max_length = max_length

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.qa_pairs)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    question = self.qa_pairs[idx][0]
    text = f"{question} {self.tokenizer.eos_token}"
    input_ids = self.tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=self.max_length, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
    attention_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)  # Assuming all tokens should be attended to

    return {
        'input_ids': torch.tensor(input_ids),
        'attention_mask': torch.tensor(attention_mask)
    }



def text_manipulation(train_dataset):
column1_values = train_dataset['Total Marks'].values
column2_values = train_dataset['Coding'].values
listOfLists = [[pair[0], pair[1]] for pair in zip(column1_values, column2_values)]

text = ""
for feedback in listOfLists:
    text += f"{feedback[0]} {feedback[1]} {tokenizer.eos_token}"
return text

training_dataset = text_manipulation(dataset)
max_length_training = max(len(tokenizer.encode(qa_pair[0],add_special_tokens=True)) for qa_pair in training_dataset)
dataset_training = FeedbackEssentials(training_dataset, tokenizer, max_length_training)
```

Here is data loader and batching

```
batch_size = 4
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset_training, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=0.9)
```

I have studied the other deeplearning answers as well. but everything seems on its right place